# Pandas: Why df.plot() not show line plots when the x axis is a datetime with millisecond precision?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to use pandas `df.plot()` to plot two lines on the same axes from two different dataframes. I want the x-axis to be datetimes. However there seems to be an issue when the datetimes are stored to different precisions in each dataframe. In the example below, `df1` has datetimes to second precision, while `df2` has datetime to millisecond precision. When I try to plot `df2` after `df1`, the line for `df2` does not plot.

I'm using pandas version 1.3.5.

```
periods = 10
dateRange = [dt.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 9, 20, i) for i in range(periods)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': dateRange, 'data': np.cumsum(np.random.randn(periods))})

periods2 = int(periods / 2)
dateRange2 = [dt.datetime(2022, 4, 12, 9, 20, 2*i, 300) for i in range(periods2)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': dateRange2, 'data': np.cumsum(np.random.randn(periods2))})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# this does not work
df1.plot(ax=ax, x='timestamp', y='data', label='df1')
df2.plot(ax=ax, x='timestamp', y='data', label='df2')

# this does work
# ax.plot(df['timestamp'], df['data'])
# ax.plot(df2['timestamp'], df2['data'])
```

[image: Resulting Plot]

Does anyone know how/why this is happening? And how I can prevent this? When doing this in practice, I typically would not know the precisions of the datetimes before plotting.

A few additional notes:

- If I make both datetimes the same precision, both lines plot fine.
- Both datetime columns have the same dtype (`datetime64[ns]`).
- If I use matplotlib's `ax.plot()` to plot the lines, they both appear fine. So I think the issue if with pandas `df.plot()`.